# The session variables are not be maintained when accessing the java application through the apache virtual host

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have installed on the same machine one apache2 server and one tomcat 7 server. The apache server is used and configured with virtual hosts enabled as is supposed to server multiple java websites. However, we have the need to serve some tomcat applications as well so we need to configure the ajp connector.

Everything goes well, I have succeeded in configuring multiple apache virtual hosts which serves tomcat apps but I have only one problem:

The session variables are not be maintained when accessing the java application through the apache virtual host. This works perfectly well when connecting directly to the 8080 port of the tomcat server.

Here is my httpd.con entry:

`ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot C:\crazyNew
ServerName crazy.com.au
ServerAlias www.crazy.com.au
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)$ /crazyNew/$1 [L,PT]
JkMount /crazyNew/* worker1
ErrorLog logs/crazy.com.au-error_log
CustomLog logs/crazy.com.au-access_log common`